# Multigráfico de cajas con varios niveles de una variable en varias generaciones

Tags: r

Me gustaría aprender a hacer un gráfico de cajas de tipo "box and whisker plot" para un caso concreto. Pongamos que el objetivo es representar la evolución de la variable "Coste" para cada nivel de otra variable denominada "Estructura" y en cada fase de un proyecto (variable "Fase").

En mi csv tengo las siguientes variables:

Fase: niveles del 1 al 7 (en saltos discretos de uno en uno, hay 7 fases).

Coste: valores que pueden variar en una escala contínua de 0 a 3.

Estructura: tenemos 3 niveles de estructura ("alta", "media", "baja").

Me gustaría representar en el eje x las fases y en el eje y los costes. Y que en el gráfico aparecieran en cada fase 3 cajas (una caja para cada nivel de la variable "Estruxtura", cada nivel en un color diferente).

Para ilustrar, hasta ahora he conseguido hacer plots con geom_point. Por ejemplo:

```
mytitle1 <- "Costes de cada tipo de estructura en cada fase"
a <-subset(global_data)
ggplot(a, aes(Fase)) + 
  labs(title=mytitle1) +
  xlab("Fase") +
  ylab("Coste") +
  geom_point(alpha=0.3,shape=16,position=position_jitter(width=.1,height=.1), aes(x=Fase, y=Coste, colour=Estructura)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "coral"), labels = c("baja", "media", "alta")) + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3))
```

Obviamente, lo que se persigue no es un gráfico representando todos los datapoints, sino un gráfico de cajas, tal y como he explicado arriba.

Comment: ¿Y aún no has probado con `geom_boxplot()`? Sería algo como `ggplot(a,aes(y=Coste,group=Fase))+geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @aldo_tapia lo he probado, pero no consigo representar tres cajas (una para cada nivel de estructura) en cada fase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para representar lo que deseas debes realizar un gráfico `ggplot()` con `x` en base a las fases, `y` al valor de coste; y para poder agregar la estructura en cada fase, usa `fill` para cambiar el color de relleno en base a estructura:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

a <- data.frame(Coste=rnorm(100*7*3),Fase=factor(rep(1:7,times=100*3)),Estructura=factor(sample(1:3,size=100*7*3,replace = T)))

a %>% ggplot(aes(x=Fase,y=Coste,fill=Estructura))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, puedes personalizar el color de relleno o borde de cada caja del boxplot.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Hola, Patricio. Incorporé `tidyverse` para usar conectores. Sin `tidyverse` sería `ggplot(a,aes(x=Fase,y=Coste,fill=Estructura))+geom_boxplot()`

Comment: Efectivamente Aldo, tu comentario lo aclara bien. Saludos